# Loading web pages from msbuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

As the last step of my msbuild script I have to load a web page from the server I have just released and make sure it contains the correct version (it is enough to just check if the version is contained textually). What is the easiest way to do it in msbuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSBuild community tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) includes a web download task that can be used to download the file.

As for how to check the file content this depends on exactly what it is you are checking for - you could write a custom task to check the file contents, or you could run an external batch file / script to do the checking (or you might be able to use the [ReadLinesFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299.aspx) task)